# Appending to Numpy array produces one big array rather than an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to append arrays to an array in the following way:

```
np.append([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9]], axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Yet, when I don't write the arrays out, but try to do something like this

```
DataMatrix = np.array([])
dataArray = np.array([])
with open("fakedata.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        #f_list = [float(i) for i in line.split(" ") or i in line.split(", ") if i.strip()]
        rr = re.findall("[+-]?\d*[\.]?\d*(?:(?:[eE])[+-]?\d+)?", line)
        dataArray=np.array([])
        for numbers in rr:
            if(numbers!=""):
                dataArray=np.append(dataArray,float(numbers))
        DataMatrix=np.append(DataMatrix,dataArray, axis=0)
print(DataMatrix)
```

it just will not work. It will produce one big array, rather than an array of arrays. Putting extra []-brackets just about anywhere did not help. Every example I find, uses explicit arrays, as shown above, rather than variables.

Comment: You might be looking for [`np.genfromtext`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) or [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

Comment: With my solution i know exactly what will be skipped, and what picked up though. I don't have a problem extracting numbers, but arranging them in a matrix afterwards. its a general problem...even if i do not read a file, but just do math, i still don't get how to arrange a matrix from arrays.

Comment: In general numpy tries to steer you away from building arrays via appending because arrays are not designed to change size, and `append` in fact just keeps making copies which is fairly inefficient. Perhaps it would be easier to just build a regular list of lists, and then convert it to an array.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data file looks like?  I second @sacuL that if it's a plain text file you should use either `np.genfromtext` or `np.loadtxt`, but how to use them depends on the specifics of your file format.  It's not really clear to me from your question what you want to achieve, and what you are getting instead.  Some sample output would be helpful.  But regardless, the code you posted is almost certainly an inefficient way of solving your problem.

Comment: I suspect also that by "array of arrays" what you mean is a multi-dimensional array (e.g. perhaps a 3-D array of 2-D matrices).  But I'm not sure.

Comment: It would appear you are trying to create a 2D array from a text file of scientific notation numbers, while stripping out the exponent and only keeping the significand. Is this correct?

Comment: @Aaron Almost. I'm trying to extract floats from a file, with all possible notations and signs. The command will keep even exponents, and the float() command can handle the notation with e or E. eg float(1e1) is 10.0. The way i programmed it, it does not matter what separates different numbers. commas, spaces, the entire LOTR book series in between...it will still pick up only the numbers. and thats just what i like...something uncrashable.

Comment: @Iguananaut I have a list in a file, eg line1: 1 2; line2: 2 3 (formatting in stackoverflow-comments doesn't allow me to use multipile lines). Then i want an array [[1 2],[2 3]], rather than [1 2 2 3]. But python doesn't want that...

Comment: @SomeGuy You can edit your question.  Please edit your question and just copy and paste some examples lines of your data into a formatted text block.

Also "python" doesn't want or not want anything.  You just need to be precise in what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: "I'm trying to extract floats from a file, with all possible notations and signs" Numpy's built-in tools will already do this faster and more robustly.  As long as the file format is simple enough.  This is why I just want to see a real example of some text from the file.  Chances are if it's simple enough this is a one-liner.

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  It's a poorly named cover for `np.concatenate`.  Neither should be used iteratively.  `append` without axis flattens the inputs.  With axis it just calls concatenate.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` styles.

Comment: @hpaulj i also tried concatenate, thinking it'd be hella smart. refuses to work too. the only way that works seems the way you suggested in your answer later on.

Comment: @AMC I have declared underscores my enemy. But a capital letter at the beginning was 'reserved' for classes, right? my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modest tweak to your answer code.  Without a txt file I can't test it, but I think it's right :)

```
alist=[]
with open("fakedata.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        rr = re.findall("[+-]?\d*[\.]?\d*(?:(?:[eE])[+-]?\d+)?", line)
        innerlist = [numbers in rr if numbers!=""]
        alist.append(innerlist)
np.array(alist, dtype=float)
```

I replaced the for loop with a list comprehension; that's mainly a syntactic cleanup.  And deferred the conversion to `float`, so `np.array` can do it on all strings 'at once'.

There have been several SO posts recently about list append versus array append.  Nearly everyone agrees that list append like this is right way.  Repeated array append/concatenate is inefficient, and hard to get right.  `np.concatenate` with a list is quite useful; `np.append` should (IMO) be depricated.

Comment: It still looks to me like this could be achieved with one of the existing text-parsing functions in Numpy.

Comment: @Iguananaut, I haven't tried to parse the `re` code so can't say whether the `numpy` functions can work or not.   `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` use the same basic parsing method - read line by line, split, and accumulate values in a list of lists.  But the generality comes with a time penalty.  `pandas` csv reader is supposed to be faster.

Comment: It depends--pandas supports multiple backends for CSV parsing.  The C-based one is stricter in what it can accept but is fasted; for more flexible parsing the Python-based one is used. [astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/index.html) also has a very powerful and fast library for parsing text files.  All that said, if bleeding-edge performance is not an immediate problem, just using the numpy built-ins is more likely to be correct and robust compared to a hand-rolled implementation with questionable regexps.

Comment: I will refer once again to a condition already quoted by the OP: "The way i programmed it, it does not matter what separates different numbers. commas, spaces, the entire LOTR book series in between...it will still pick up only the numbers." The goal is to extract only numbers from a file that may have varying delimiters, or other non-numeric data mixed in with numeric data. The regex could possibly be improved, but is not complicated, and is functional for the purpose stated.

Comment: yupp, thank you. i eventually came up with the same solution. thanks anyways.

Comment: @hpaulj you "deferred the conversion to float, so np.array can do it on all strings 'at once'". What means 'at once' in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file looks something like this:

```
1e1 1e2 -1e3
2.4e5 4.5e6 1.8e1
-1.1 -0.6 1.11
```

You can use [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import io
>>> matrix = """\
1e1 1e2 -1e3
2.4e5 4.5e6 1.8e1
-1.1 -0.6 1.11"""
>>> file = io.StringIO(matrix)
>>> np.loadtxt(file)
array([[ 1.00e+01,  1.00e+02, -1.00e+03],
       [ 2.40e+05,  4.50e+06,  1.80e+01],
       [-1.10e+00, -6.00e-01,  1.11e+00]])
```

In this case the default arguments to `np.loadtxt` will work, but if this isn't the exact format of your file there are various tweaks that can be made.  To pass it a filename directly as in your case you can use `np.loadtxt('fakedata.txt')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the only way that i manage, is to define a normal array (DataMatrix=[], rather than DataMatrix=np.array([])), and then use np.array(array) at the end to get it into the form i want:

```
DataMatrix=[]
with open("fakedata.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        rr = re.findall("[+-]?\d*[\.]?\d*(?:(?:[eE])[+-]?\d+)?", line)
        dataArray=[]
        for numbers in rr:
            if(numbers!=""):
                dataArray.append(float(numbers))
        DataMatrix.append(dataArray)
np.array(DataMatrix)        
print(np.array(DataMatrix))
```

Considering that I'm a total programming noob, this is probably not the smartest way to do so. But well...thanks for the downvote...

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a bad way to do it.. Python lists are designed to be appended to, while numpy arrays are not. Your required flexibility in parsing the file does restrict you from using the builtin numpy file input routines, and this solves that problem.

Comment: If you could be a little more clear about what you're trying to achieve I'm certain I could give you a better solution.

Comment: @Aaron What do you mean with "numpy arrays are not designed to be appended to". I think it's quite clear that I'd have no clue why that should be?

Comment: @SomeGuy a numpy array in memory is fixed in size, while python lists allocate extra space so it can grow at a later time. `np.append` does not actually "append" to the existing array, but instead creates an entire new array and copies the data to it.

Comment: On another note, your original code was not working because `np.append` is more similar to `list.extend` rather than `list.append`.

Comment: @SomeGuy "I have been sufficiently clear" no you haven't.  As an expert I can tell you you haven't.  But I would like to be able to help. All I'm asking is that you edit your question to include a snippet of the file you're trying to read from and it will probably clear things up a bit.

Comment: @Iguananaut the comments and the regex line make it quite clear the contents of the data file. I understand you want to be helpful but the "as an expert" is kinda condescending. From the information available, it is not difficult to infer everything necessary to answer the question.

Comment: That's not necessarily true--without an example file we have no way of knowing that the OP's code is correct for handling the input.  I'm sorry to come off condescending.

Comment: @Aaron thank you for elaborating on this. Is there any site where i can read up on such efficiency issues? where do you know that from? how can i know what's efficient and what's not? still a mystery to me, even though i'm using python for almost 2 years now,